# Custom made js script works in debug mode but not on Azure

Tags: javascript, jquery, azure

Did somebody maybe had a problem related to this.
I have made a custom made js script, with some functionalities I use in MVC View page. I reference that script inside of View:

```
<script src="~/js/saveNewMeeting.js"></script>
```

When I test my functionality locally from debug mode everything works great. But when I publish my project to Azure I do not have functionalities from saveNewMeeting.js.

When I go and look console in Chrome I can see saveNewMeeting.js in js resources. So the file is loaded. Then when I put break points on code to check if it runs initially and I notice that main block never runs:

```
(function () {
    var addNewMeetingModal = document.getElementById('createNewEventModal');
    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

    document.ready = function () {
        $('#startdatetimepicker').datetimepicker({
            daysOfWeekDisabled: [0, 6]
        });
        $('#enddatetimepicker').datetimepicker({
            daysOfWeekDisabled: [0, 6]
        });
        PopulateVenueSelectList();
    }

    span.onclick = function () {
        addNewMeetingModal.style.display = "none";
    }

    function ClearPopupFormValues() {
        $('#eventID').val("");
        $('#eventTitle').val("");
        $('#enddatepicker').val("");
        $('#startdatepicker').val("");
        $('#endtimepicker').val("");
        $('#starttimepicker').val("");
        $('#venue').empty();
    }

    function PopulateVenueSelectList() {
        var venueSelect = $('#venue');

        venueSelect.prepend("<option value='' selected='selected'></option>");

        $.getJSON("/Meeting/GetAllActiveVenues", null, function (venues) {
            $.each(venues, function (i, venue) {
                $('<option>', {
                    value: venue.id
                }).html(venue.name).appendTo(venueSelect);
            });
        });
    }
})();
```

It creates `addNewMeetingModal` and `span` variables but never go inside of `document.ready` block. So something is wrong with events.

My thought then was, ok maybe I can use `window.onload` event instead. But when I've changed my code in that way and it stopped working in debug mode now.

Does someone have an idea why this problem with events happening?

jQuery is referenced in `_Layout.cshtml`.

Answer (score 0):

Your way to bind the ready event seems to be wrong. Please just follow the standard jQuery coding samples.

Just try for example

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    // Add more from the Code here


    $('#startdatetimepicker').datetimepicker({
        daysOfWeekDisabled: [0, 6]
    });
    $('#enddatetimepicker').datetimepicker({
        daysOfWeekDisabled: [0, 6]
    });
    PopulateVenueSelectList();
});
```